# How to use the captor function with jest-mock-extended?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, argumentcaptor

I'm trying to write a test where I'd like to capture the argument of a function. If I understand correctly I'd have to use `captor()` for this but I can't dig up any examples of how to do so. Simply passing it as an argument to the function I'm mocking gives me a compiler error:

```
const scheduleArg = captor<JobDescriptor<JsonObject>>();

scheduler.schedule(scheduleArg) //  error

scheduler.schedule.calledWith(scheduleArg) //  error
```

How do I use `captor()` properly?

Answer (score 1):

A `captor()` works like

```
const myCaptor = captor();

expect(...).toHaveBeenCalledWith(any(), myCaptor);
expect(myCaptor.value).toBe('someValue');
```

and also

```
const myCaptor = captor();

expect(...).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, any(), myCaptor);
expect(...).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, any(), myCaptor);

expect(myCaptor.values).toEqual(['someValue', 'otherValue']);
expect(myCaptor.value).toBe('otherValue');
```